# Creating jobs in Databricks Asset Bundles based on a variable(region)

Tags: databricks, databricks-asset-bundle

We are using Databricks Asset bundles to create databricks resources and jobs. Our current databricks instance is in US region and it has almost 30 jobs created so far.
Now, we need to create a databricks instance in EU region and for EU, new 2 jobs will be created. We want to be able to use the same repository as we don't want to create new repository for every new region we support.
However, as per DAB documentation, there can be only 1 databricks.yaml file. And I can not find a way to create a job based on a condition. Someone knows if it is possible to restrict a job creation based on the value of a variable may be in databricks.yaml file?